# How to update record using Entity Framework 6 MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am looking for the correct way to update a record using Entity Framework 6 MYSQL.

Below is what I'm using right now.

```
    public void Update(User user)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataSystemDbContext())
        {
            ctx.Users.Attach(user);
            ctx.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And on my unit test.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task User_Update()
    {

        var userService = new UserService();
        var user = userService.GetById(1);
        user.FullName = "Test Fullname";
        userService.Update(user);
        var updatedUser = userService.GetById(1);

        Assert.AreEqual(user.FullName, updatedUser.FullName);
    }
```

When it executes all my user records are updated.

This is also related to my another post. But on my another post it's using a live context, unlike this one.

[MySQL Entity Framework 6 Update affecting all rows Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008874/mysql-entity-framework-6-update-affecting-all-rows-code-first)

Comment: Please show which SQL UPDATE statements are executed.

Comment: what do you mean? you want to see the generated sql by the Enttiy Framework. Entity Framework calls the User_Update procedure but its forget to include the where clause with the ID.

Comment: You didn't say you called a stored procedure, even though the linked question does. Also the sentence "on this post it's using a live context, unlike this one" isn't clear. What is "this" and "this"? Do you mean you're mocking the context in the current question?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by commenting out or not using the generated procedure for CRUD.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);    
     // Mapp all entities in a single line.    
     //modelBuilder.Types().Configure(t => t.MapToStoredProcedures());
}
```

Generated SQL

```
UPDATE `Users` SET `Email`=@gp1 WHERE `Id` = 6
-- @gp1: 'myemail@gmail.com' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 17)
-- Executing asynchronously at 25/06/2018 8:30:21 AM +08:00
-- Completed in 2 ms with result: 1
```

I'm not sure if the MySQL Provider has a bug or not.

- Entity Framework v6.1.3
- MySQL.Data.Entity v6.10.7
- MySQL.Data v6.10.7